# Адаптивная google maps карта.

Tags: html5, css3, google-maps-api

Доброго дня. Имеется карта, которая на больших разрешениях выглядит неплохо, но при уменьшении экрана не адаптивная. Подскажите, как можно ее сделать таковой? Width 100% к блоку карте - не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Не моё,  взял тут: ostraining.com/blog/coding/responsive-google-maps/

```
<style type="text/css">
.map-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.map-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
<div class="map-responsive">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d386950.6511603643!2d-73.70231446529533!3d40.738882125234106!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNueva+York!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sus!4v1445032011908" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```